# Get concrete Type from Object DataSource and use this type variable in a cast operation

Tags: c#, reflection, object, types, concrete

I have a

```
public object DataSource {get;set} and a public string DisplayMember {get;set}
```

The object can take everything like an IList or a CustomerListDataSet.

I do not know what the user will set in the DataSource.

I tried this

```
Type myType = DataSource.GetType().UnderlyingSystemType;

??? myUnknownObjectInstance = (mytype)DataSource;
```

I guess it is not possible even with Reflection access a myUnknownObjectInstance.PropertyNameFromDisplayMember and assign it a value like "Peter" ?

Comment: You can't do what you're trying to do, so try telling us what problem you were trying to solve that led you down this false path.

Answer (score 0):

Could you refactor the class to use generics?  so that you have a datasource of the generic type?

Answer (score 0):

You can determine your type explicitely by a

```
if (DataSource is IList)
{
 ...
}
else if (DataSource is DataTable)
{
...
}
```

etc

But if DataSource is not generic, there is no way you can do that cast like you specified.  You can cast it, when it type is specified as a parameter.

You can access property by writing

```
PropertyInfo pi = DataSource.GetType().GetProperty(DisplayMember);
pi.SetValue(DataSource, "Peter");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need `DataSource.GetType()`